# Multiple gunicorn workers prevents flask app from making https calls

Tags: python, flask, openssl, gunicorn

A simple flask app accepts requests and then makes calls to https endpoints. Using gunicorn with multiple worker processes leads to ssl failures.

Using `flask run` works perfectly, albeit slowly.

Using `gunicorn --preload --workers 1` also works perfectly, albeit slowly.

Changing to `gunicorn --preload --workers 10` very frequently fails with `[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC]` which leads me to think that there's some per-connection state that is being messed up. But, gunicorn is supposed to fork before beginning service of requests.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was using --preload to avoid having each worker retrieve initial oauth context for use in some of the https webapi calls. Rule of thumb should be that when doing fork() (in gunicorn), you really need to understand what is happening with the ssl state.

Solution was to disable the preload and do the oauth individually in each worker.